# Bouml Add operations to a class in a class diagram in bulk

Tags: uml

I am using the software BOUML for uml modelling. My class has around 30 methods. Is there anyway to add operations to a class in class diagram in bulk(eg. from a list or file) rather than one by one in this tool

Answer (score 1):

Bouml allows to duplicates operations (or other element), you also have an entry to redefine inherited operations

You says "from a list or file" does this means you have source(s) file(s) defining your class(es) ? if yes you can set/update your model using reverse/roundtrip supposing the source language has reverse/roundtrip of course

Answer (score 0):

I am not a BOUML expert but I am pretty sure that you should be able to extend it in order to define your own import or simply import some XMI file or reverse some Java or C++ code for example.

Regards,